# Send borders to the back of the text in cell

Tags: excel, vba, text, border, cell

I suspect this question doesn't have a satisfactory answer, but I'll ask it anyway: is there a way to send the "inside borders" of a cell - specifically the `xlDiagonalDown` and `xlDiagonalUp` ones, but the question can potentially be extended to the `xlInsideHorizontal` and `xlInsideVertical` ones - *to the back* of the text in cell (or, if you like, bring the text *in front* of them)? If the answer is the expected no, can those borders be drawn using a semi-transparent or translucent color **so they're not obstructing the view of the text inside the cell** (like below)?

[image: Excel Diagonal Borders Overriding Cell Text]

I'm asking this because I'm drawing a map in the sheet I'm working with and I was wondering if I could represent the roads/railroads on the map using the cells' diagonal borders. Right now I'm successfully representing the rivers using the `xlEdgeBottom` and `xlEdgeRight` borders and I'm already representing the roads/railroads using abbreviations within the cell value string (e.g. `roa` for roads, `rai` for railroads), but thought about making the routes representation more expressive visually. I tried using the cells' diagonal borders, but Excel seems to override the cell text when drawing them - and yes, I'm assigning values to the cells from an array *after* I'm drawing the borders (simplified sample below).

```
    Cells(3, 3).Borders(xlDiagonalUp).Weight = xlThin
    Cells(3, 3).Borders(xlDiagonalUp).Color = vbWhite
    Cells(3, 3).Borders(xlDiagonalDown).Weight = xlThin
    Cells(3, 3).Borders(xlDiagonalDown).Color = vbWhite
```

*Note: I'm not thinking about background images or shapes because of speed considerations. My "map" is made of around 26000 cells (basically `Byte` x `Byte`).*

Comment: I don't think this is possible.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately I kind of expected that, like I said. Well, at least I asked...

Comment: Anyway, just for the record (not that my opinion matters anyway in the grand scheme of things), but the behavior seems a bit illogical to me, as one would expect the text to be "on top" of the visual elements in the cell format (like borders, interior colors, patterns and such). What happens is that the text is indeed "in front" of the interior color ... but is strangely "behind" similar visual features like patterns and borders.